# samba 4 force user

Tags: permissions, samba, password

I have a directory with files owned by Linux user `quux`. I want to give access to it over CIFS using Samba 4 for two persons so they have different usernames `foo` and `bar` and passwords but access the same files under the same Unix UID and GID of `quux`.

In Samba 3 it was possible by using `force user` and `forced group` parameters of share configuration in `smb.conf` but the options are no longer supported in Samba 4.

Is something similar possible with Samba 4?

Upd: We use samba to edit files on development Linux server from Windows PCs. For simplicity of deployment it's better to have the same file ownership and permissions on production and development servers.

Ideally every developer should have single pair of username/password to remember and use it to connect to any project at any server as opposed to having different credentials for different projects and/or servers.

Comment: What's the motivation to have them use the `quux` user? If you have acl's enabled that should provide you with a way to explicitly set rights rather than forcing two different users to use the same UID. `force user` is a kludge to work around older issues anyways.

Comment: Edited question to clarify.

Comment: Sounds like `quux` is supposed to be a proxy for group access to a particular directory tree/file. Is there an objection to modelling group memberships according to organizational roles and using `setfacl` to give those groups and individual users access to those files?

Comment: Basically, that's more in line with "best practices" since people are using their own accounts and changes in organizational roles can be more easily managed from one location (the point of group membership in whatever group is supposed to represent their role).